# How to change data source (different structure) in power bi

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop, powerbi-datasource

I've got a power bi report built. I want to change the data source.  The new data source has 4-5 new columns.  How should I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a difficult job but not impossible. You said you have 4/5 new columns in your new data source. Which is not an issue if you have all existing columns available in the new source that are already in used in the Report and Data Model. There are different approach and manual work to achieve the requirement. Please check **[This Tutorial](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/how-to-change-data-source-of-existing-report-in-power-bi/)** where I found a detail and good explanation for your case.